# Open .rar files on Slackware

Tags: extract, rar, slackware

How can I open .rar files in Slackware?

Comment: With respect to both answers below, you would be better off using the SlackBuilds for [p7zip](http://slackbuilds.org/repository/13.37/system/p7zip/) and [unrar](http://slackbuilds.org/repository/13.37/system/unrar/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)(check the bottom of the page for the linux stuff), best archiver in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

download the `unrar` package from http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm

Comment: unrar is free so it's available as native package in many distros. Installing native package provided by distro is better solution since it's maintained.